# Is it possible to get a word count of a pdf from the console with MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, vbscript, latex

I often use MS Word to open `.pdfs` generated by latex just so I can get a quick accurate word count of the document as it is. But it seems like there should be a faster way of doing this if all I am doing is opening the file and looking at the bottom right for 1 second.

Is there a way I can do this from the command line?

Comment: There are many ways to either let latex or your favourite editor count the words. The difficult thing is how do you define a word?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I did some googling and it seems like there are a variety of different pearl scripts that can do latex word counting but I kind of felt that Microsoft has probably solved the problem of which of these is the best many years ago - so when I found out word could open pdfs directly, I was very happy to use it for the word count.

Comment: I think that the other ways to count words are not necessarily less accurate than using word - they might just use a different formula. However without knowing the formula used by word it is impossible to judge which is better.

Comment: @samcarter agreed

Comment: anyway, it is nice that you share your knowledge with the community!

Answer (score 1):

I have quickly hacked together a small `.vbs` script that will do exactly this. While it does use a hardcoded file, it's um better than nothing.

1. Make a script called `wc.vbs` and then put this in it:

   ```vb
   Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   word.Visible = False
   Set doc = word.Documents.Open("<replace with absolute path to your .docx/.pdf>")
   docWordCount = doc.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
   word.Quit
   Dim StdOut : Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)
   WScript.Echo docWordCount & " words"
   ```
2. Open powershell in the directory you saved `wc.vbs` and run `cscript .\wc.vbs` and you'll get back the word count :)

---

*p.s*: This script does not use `Words.Count` to count words because I found it to be giving very different numbers to the ones I was actually seeing in MS word with my eyes. So I instead used the `Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)` mentioned here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/291447/word-count-appears-inaccurate-when-you-use-the-vba-words-property I have no idea why it works because I learned for the first time how to run a vbs script minutes before I posted this answer.

Comment: This may be dependent on whether the original text is part of the PDF or if the PDF is image-only. The latter may require OCR'ing the PDF and 1) generating a new PDF which is no longer image only, or b) piping the text generated by the OCR process through wc from GNU Text Utilities (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/247268/2909179)